# Is Foreign Direct Investments per capita a count variable?

Tags: r, regression

I was doing a multiple linear regression in which the dependent variable was the FDI per capita. However, it turned out that the data has a negative binomial distribution. That is why I tried to use the negative binomial regression, which works properly.

However, I have a fundamental question is it possible to consider FDI per capita as a count variable. Since negative binomial regression work with count data.

By definition count variable is number of accidents, number of suicides.

So theoretically FDI per capita is also considered to be a count variable, since it is a number of FDI per capita. My data is integer and non-negative.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Edited the question in order to make more sense .

Comment: Hint: a count must be a non-negative whole number.  Are your FDI per capita values such numbers?  In almost all such cases, questions about "what kind of a variable is so-and-so" are beside the point.  Perhaps you really ought to be asking about the applicability of your negative binomial procedure to your data.

Comment: Yes, the FDI per capita is a non-negative whole number. I tried doing multiple linear regression but the data has a negative binomial distribution. In short, it is skewed to the left. If I am doing the multiple linear regression I have really significant outliers and if I try doing robust regression then it only confirms that the outliers were really significant and that is it.

Comment: You most likely mean your data are skewed to the *right*--they have a long positive tail.  But what is your question?  What exactly do you mean by "consider FDI per capita to be a count variable"?  According to your comments it is and according to your question the regression works.

Comment: Yeah, the regression work fine. I am just wondering if it is appropriate or even allowed to consider FDI per capita to be a count variable?

Comment: But what difference would that make to anything at all?  If it weren't a "count variable," how could that possibly change your results?  I may be misunderstanding your question because of the possibility that we have different concepts of what "count variable" entails, which is why I am asking for your explanation of that.

Comment: As I understand and read observations count data can take only the non-negative integer values

Comment: And that's exactly what you have told us about your variable: "Yes, the FDI per capita is a non-negative whole number."  So it seems you don't have a question to ask.

Comment: Since your new post appears to be an elaboration of this one, I am closing this one with a link to the new one.